# ngClick on anchor tags causing problems in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

I've got ngClick directives on the anchors tags inside my main navigation, to make the menu "disappear" off canvas after clicking it:

`<a href="/#/profile" ng-click="showNav = false">`

It's functioning all right. However, I recently noticed an error (in the console) that occurs when I'm changing view through those anchor tags:

> Infinite $digest
>
> Loop error in component $rootScope

This is how I handles my routes:

```
$routeProvider.when('/register', {
   templateUrl: 'assets/templates/register.html',
   controller: 'RegistrationController'
});
```

Is this because I change view at the same time as I'm setting "showNav" to false? Is this even the right way to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want menu to disappear - you stay href empty. If you need moving to new controller then set `showNav = false` in profile controller. So I mean you need something one - either ng-click or href, not both.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the href and altered my ngClick to call a function that changes the location as well as sets the showNaw to false

Comment: @tobiasandersen, you better return href and put `showNav = false` in controller where this href links to.

Comment: I can see why that would be preferable. However it doesn't work with the structure I've got now. Since showNav is used in a wider scope.

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only make guessing but try inject $rootScope and then switch it like this `$rootScope.showNav = false` in your profile controller.

Answer (score 0):

tie the showing and hiding of your anchor tag to the url not the user clicking i.e.:

```
<a ng-if="location.path() != '/profile' href="/#/profile"></a>
```

in your controller:

```
function mycontroller($scope,$location) {
$scope.location = $location;
}
```